# How to make the output less verbose in Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, verbose, verbosity, tavern

I am running pytest with tavern for a small testing API project.
Failing a test, throws me a bunch of verbose errors plus the response I am expecting to get (why it failed). How can I make pytest less verbose?

I tried 
pytest --tb=short, 
pytest -vv, 
pytest --tavern-beta-new-traceback and none worked as expected just telling me the reason it failed. Something like:

```
E   tavern.util.exceptions.TestFailError: Test 'Do something' failed:
    - Status code was 200, expected 300
-------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call --------------------------------------------------------
base.py                     41 ERROR    Status code was 200, expected 300
==================================================== 1 failed in 0.38 seconds =====================================================
```

Maybe is something wrong with how tavern handles errors or pytest?

Comment: Having the same problem. I saw that [your issue](https://github.com/taverntesting/tavern/issues/354) was closed, saying that it's a pytest config problem but none of the  command line options provided in the documention links work as intended.

Answer (score 5):

Running `pytest -vv` should make your output more verbose. If you want your output to be less verbose, try `pytest -q` or `pytest --quiet`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes using a higher log level might reduce the pytest output clutter. For example, using

```
pytest <my_test_folder> --log-cli-level=warning
```

Different options for log level (from most verbose to least verbose) are: `debug`, `info`, `warning`, `error` and `critical`.

Comment: Where in the documentation might I have found those log levels documented?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the verbosity of the output with `--verbosity=VERBOSE` below:

```
pytest --help
...
--verbosity=VERBOSE   Set verbosity. Default: 0.
```

So, `--verbosity=1` below can get the output verbosely. *It is identical to `-v` and `--verbose`:

```
pytest --verbosity=1
```

And, `--verbosity=0` below can get the output normally:

```
pytest --verbosity=0
```

`--verbosity=-1` below can get the output less verbosely. *It is identical to `-q` and `--quiet`:

```
pytest --verbosity=-1
```